# Google api not loading, despite being literally copy + pasted?

Tags: html, api, google-maps

For whatever reason, I can't manage to get this api to load in this file. (Yes, I know I'm probably using awful methods for other things, but obviously I'm no pro yet)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Street Ink - Homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
```

```
<div id = "mainBody">
    <div id = "banner"><img src = "http://placehold.it/700x250" alt = "Placeholder" /></div>
    <span id = "header">Main Street Ink</span>
    <span id = "subHead">Located at 529 N. Main Street, Findlay, OH</span>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is in styles.css?

Comment: Just
#map_canvas {
 width: 500;
 height: 400;

}

Comment: That isn't correct should be `#map_canvas {width: 500px; height: 400px;}`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: THANK YOU! Now is there a way I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: You mark it answered by [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have posted your CSS:

```
#map_canvas { 
  width: 500; 
  height: 400; 
}
```

The problem was a typo, missing the "px", should be

```
#map_canvas {
  width: 500px; 
  height: 400px;
}
```